# Can't reach server without proxy (website down from my home)

Tags: security, wordpress, firefox, google-chrome, ip-blocking

I have a website hosted on Hostinger

However I am experiencing problems with my wordpress site.
This is really annoying. If I understood the situation right, The server is blocking me or denying access to my own website.

When I visit the site with google chrome, it returns:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find

Same thing happens to firefox!

> Firefox can't find the server

but when I do a check if my site is online and working through `http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/`
it says that the site is working and up.

Another thing, I access the website through a proxy, both on chrome and in firefox, and t works.

Why is this? I have also recently installed the plugin `Better Wp Security` 5 days ago.
Could the plugin have caused it? but I don't remember setting any IP's to be blocked.

Also, this happens at random times, sometimes I can access it, sometimes it fails to reach the server. I am currently developing the site live.

Was I blocked by the server for frequently refreshing the page? (duh, I'm a developer and I need to refresh to see changes.)
or
is this a problem with my ISP's DNS server?
How can I resolve? and what are the possible fixes?

Thanks in advance!

-Jomar

Comment: What's the website?

Comment: Err.. I'm really sorry that I can't give the link to the website.
I can not expose that I am a part of it's development.
Thanks Though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robbie mentions, the URL of your site would help, so we could see if we can access it.

You can easily check if its a DNS issue by pinging your site when you cant access it. If your domain name resolves to an IP, then DNS is not at fault.

Better WP security sounds like a likely culprit. Why don't you use your proxy to access your site, and check its settings, or at least disable it temporarily so you can eliminate / isolate the problem.

Comment: I did, and strangely, it seems to have fixed the problem.
I'm not sure what's causing WP security to do such.

I have added a lot of custom made PHP.
I'm not sure why..

also, I have installed bulletproof security on the way.
I think this could be a plugin incompatibility..

Thanks anyway..